# custom theme background color

Tags: javascript, reactjs, themes, background-color, material-ui

I have material-ui@next installed and I want to customize the background color of the theme.

I tried this:

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: createPalette({
    type: 'light',
    primary: purple,
    background: {
      default: '#303030',
    },
  }),
});
```

And this.

```
<MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
```

But the background color is still white when it should change to red.

Answer (score 36):

I also faced this issue. To fix this, import CssBaseline:

```
import CssBaseline from '@mui/material/CssBaseline';
```

Then add it like this:

```
<MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
    <CssBaseline />
```

Using CssBaseline while setting background color as follows the color gets applied:

```
import { createTheme } from '@mui/material/styles';

const theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    background: {
      default: "#303030"
    }
  }
});
```

You can find a working snippet [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/kkpw0y1vm5).

Comment: It's a simple mistake to make but it's obvious after being fixed. The CssBaseline needs to access the theme for the background color and has to be a child element  in order to access it.